# Calculate the cumulative distinct count of sleepers based on day

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've a requirement, where i will need to calculate the cumulative distinct count of sleepers on a daily basis, my current input is as shown below, for the cal_date='2022-02-27' my unique sleepers count=1685606 and for cal_date='2022-02-28', i will need to calculate the distinct sleepers count which will be the combination of the both the dates('2022-02-27', ''2022-02-28') and like that it should follow the cumulative date i.e for '2022-03-01' distinct sleepers count will be the combination of the dates('2022-02-27', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-01')

Current input:

[image]

I've used the below WindowSpec, which is currently summing-up the previous and current date values which is wrong.

Current output:

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

windowSpec = Window.orderBy('cal_date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df_new = df.withColumn('mtd_active_sleepers_cummulative', F.sum('value').over(windowSpec)).drop('value')
display(df_new)
```

Instead of calling F.sum('value').over(windowSpec), can we use count (distinct sleeper_id) over a windowSpec. Any pointers would help.

Comment: You would need to use this window function before the aggregation, counting the distincts

Comment: @LuizViola, please can you elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following df:

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('a','2022-02-27'),
('b','2022-02-27'),
('a','2022-02-27'),
('c','2022-02-28'),
('b','2022-02-28'),
('d','2022-02-28'),
('a','2022-03-01'),
('e','2022-03-01'),
('b','2022-03-01'),
('d','2022-03-01'),
  ], ['sleepers_type', 'date'])\
.withColumn('date', F.to_date('date', 'y-M-d'))

+-------------+----------+
|sleepers_type|      date|
+-------------+----------+
|            a|2022-02-27|
|            b|2022-02-27|
|            a|2022-02-27|
|            c|2022-02-28|
|            b|2022-02-28|
|            d|2022-02-28|
|            a|2022-03-01|
|            e|2022-03-01|
|            b|2022-03-01|
|            d|2022-03-01|
+-------------+----------+
```

Now you can use `approx_count_distinct` to count the distincts in a Window Function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

from pyspark.sql import Window as W
w = W.orderBy('date').rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df\
    .withColumn('cumul_sum', F.approx_count_distinct(F.col('sleepers_type')).over(w))\
    .groupby('date').agg(F.max('cumul_sum').alias('value'))\
    .select('value', F.col('date').alias('cal_date'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-----+----------+
|value|cal_date  |
+-----+----------+
|2    |2022-02-27|
|4    |2022-02-28|
|5    |2022-03-01|
+-----+----------+
```